Is this sentence correct: I had read that was bad season.?
Is this sentence correct?

I had read that was bad season.

Duolingo complains about it and prefers

I had read that that season was bad.

Is it because it has no subject in the first version?

Yes. You could also say "I had read that it was a bad season" (if you mean that the season in question was a bad one).

The subject is "I" in both cases, but something is missing. It is not a great solution to settle on "That that" if there's a way around it.

Asking "is this correct" is off-topic here as this is not a proofreading site. Your question needs to be on a specific point of learning English. Did you do any research? It so, include it, and explain why you think your sentence is wrong or right.

You can always discard the first "that" (a "that-relativizer") in contexts like Duolingo's suggested I had read that that season was bad. The reason your original version I had read that was bad season is invalid is because there's a missing indefinite article, as pointed out by Kate. There's nothing wrong with I had read that was a bad season (where the remaining "that" refers to a season that was previously mentioned in the conversation). It's entirely a stylistic choice if you want to include a "that-relativizer". Native speakers barely even notice the that that repetition.

@YosefBaskin: It's misleading to say It is not a great solution to settle on "That that" if there's a way around it. Learners might have to think about that that, but native speakers really don't care. Bear in mind that in almost every case, if the word that occurs twice in succession, the first instance (the optional "that-relativizer") will be unstressed (vowel reduced to a schwa), and the second instance will carry stress. To native speakers, these are two completely different words that just happen to be written the same.

If this is a sentence you wrote, please edit to tell more about the exact meaning you want. Duolingo has made a guess, but it might have guessed wrong. For instance, it might be that the right version would be "I had read that it was a bad season." It might even be that you're talking about how to add spices to food, not about a portion of the year! Please edit to tell more.

@FumbleFingers Sorry, we can disagree without labeling it misleading. Just saying.

@YosefBaskin: But there really is nothing remotely "remarkable" about that that in the cited context.

Duolingo is correct that your first sentence isn't quite right, and you're right that you're missing a noun/pronoun and an article.

I had read that was bad season.

Any of the below options would be acceptable:

I had read that it was a bad season.
I had read that this was a bad season.
I had read that this season was bad.
I had read that the season was bad.
That season was bad, I read.

The provided solution is grammatically correct but awkward. It's best to avoid sentences that use "that that" in a row if at all possible.
In modern spoken (and less formal written) English, the word "that" can also be omitted from constructs of [Subject] + [Verb] + that. Such as:

"I read that the moon is big." -> can be "I read the moon is big."
"I heard that she likes ice cream." -> can be "I heard she likes ice cream."

So the most common way to verbally say your sentence would probably be:

I had read that was a bad season. with a slight verbal pause between "read" and "that" to show "that" is a pronoun for "season".


double thats do work: I had read that that was a bad season.

It's because you are not telling the reader which season was bad.
You need to say  (after "I had read that") "that Autumn was a bad season" or "Winter was a bad season." Alternatively, that was a bad season, or "it was a bad season."

After reading the answer of @Friendly I realized that I'm actually telling the reader which season – that season. The only thing that was missing in my sentence was a because the app didn't let me add the article.
